# Increase column position

Tags: mysql

Following code working perfectly on exist data:

```
INSERT INTO `cats`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `slug`, `position`) 
VALUES ('',0,'Test4','test4',(SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM cats as g WHERE parent_id = 0));
```

data from mysql

```
-------------------------------------------
id | parent_id |  name  |  slug  | position
-------------------------------------------
1      0          test     test      1
2      0          test2    test2     2
3      2          test3    test3     1
```

When i try to add new record with following code

```
INSERT INTO `cats`(`id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `slug`, `position`) 
VALUES ('',1,'Test4','test4',(SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM cats as g WHERE parent_id = 1));
```

Result is: **#1048 - Column 'position' cannot be null**

If possible solution with one command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a different `parent_id` value in each `insert`.

Perhaps your query

```
(SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM cats as g WHERE parent_id = 1)
```

is returning a `NULL` value.

Perhaps use `COALESCE` as in below - to force a value of 1 for example:

```
COALESCE((SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM cats as g WHERE parent_id = 1),1)
```

Link [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php)

EDIT:

This is the right approach but it can be more efficient to do the `coalesce()` in the subquery:

```
(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(position), 1) FROM cats as g WHERE parent_id = 1)
```

Comment: Yes this is best solution Thank you!